# Show $F$ is not a Always a Field With the Given Conditions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $F$ be a collection of subsets of $X$, where $X\in F$, $F$ is closed under complimentation, and is closed under finite *disjoint* unions.

I need to find an example of $F$ meeting the following conditions that is not a field.

A collection of subsets of $X$, $F$, is a field if the following hold:

1) $\emptyset \in X$

2) if $A\in F$ then $A^c\in F$

3) if $A, B\in F$ then $A \bigcup B\in F$

Clearly for the $F$ given to me 2) holds for it since $F$ is closed uner complimentation, and 1) holds since $X\in F$ implies $X^c\in F$ which implies $\emptyset \in F$.

So conditions 1 & 2 clearly hold for $F$, so I need to find $F$ that fits the requirements but contradicts 3).  So I need to have an F where two non-disjoint sets in F doesn't have their union in $F$.

This is where I get stuck, I can't find an example.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've got it backwards: You need an $F$ where the union of *disjoint* sets is contained, but their is some pair of *overlapping* sets whose union is not contained. I believe the simplest example can be found in a set $X$ of 4 elements.

Comment: Ahhh yes I do.  I will try to think of sets with 4 elements thanks